# add array to array state in react hooks gives a number

Tags: reactjs

i declare a Array sate and want to add some Arrays in it like :

```
const [number, setNumber] = useState(3);
const [TimePickerList, setTimePickerList] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
        
        for(var i = 0; i < number ; i++) { 
           setTimePickerList(TimePickerList.push([]))
           
        }
        console.log(TimePickerList); // it gives me an array like this : [[],[],[]]
    }, [number])
```

but when i get log from TimePickerList in another function it gives me a number (3).
and i lost my arrays in my array state (I expected something like this : [[],[],[]] But While gives me the length of the array)
***I also used concat() but it gives me an empty Array and doesn't add my Arrays***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push the values in an empty array. Then set it to your state

```
    const [number, setNumber] = useState(3);
    const [TimePickerList, setTimePickerList] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
          const list = [];
          for(var i = 0; i < number ; i++) { 
             list.push(i);
          }
          setTimePickerList(list);
    }, [number]);
```

Comment: thanks man it exactly what i want wish you luck

Comment: You are welcome bro. Good luck you too.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't mutate the state object, it messes up change detection,
2. and the value of the expression `someArray.push(someValue)` is `someValue`.

Instead do something like

```
let newList = [...TimePickerList];

for(let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    newList = [...newList, []];
}

setTimePickerList(newList);
```

Comment: thanks man for take your time and your awesome awnser it works too

Answer (score 1):

The state works a bit differently as compared to normal variables and shouldn't be updated directly (for reasons mentioned here https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/why-we-should-never-update-react-state-directly-c1b794fac59b)

So, I'd recommend making three changes to your code.

1. Create a temporary variable which contains your list inside the (and you can update it wherever and however you want), e.g. inside your useEffect before for loop `const list = [];`
2. Push whatever you want to push inside the variable. So for the above code, it would be:
   `for(let i = 0; i < number ; i++) { list.push(whatever you need to push to the array); }`
3. set the state using that variable. In your case, after the for loop, update the state as: `setTimePickerList(list)`

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to push an element to a state containing an array is using a callback:

```
const [number, setNumber] = useState(3);
const [TimePickerList, setTimePickerList] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
 let list = [];
 for(let i = 0; i < number ; i++) { 
   list.push([])
 }
 setTimePickerList((currentArray) => [...currentArray,...list])
},[number])
```

The only thing I'm guessing is: why adding empty arrays? You know that filling up these arrays will be a nightmare and since you are using a complicated data structure maybe useState is not what you want to use?

**NOTICE**:

Since changes of state are not performed synchronously you cannot watch the updates to `TimePickerList` directly in the first `useEffect`. To see how it changes add a second `useEffect`:

```
useEffect(()=>{
  console.log(timePickerList);
},[timePickerList])
```

Comment: thanks man for take your time i learn a lot from your awnser wish you luck

Answer (score 1):

I've tried your code and it gives a correct output as you wish.

[image: output]

But if you want to set value based on a prev value it's better to pass a callback into setter function which receives current state value

Another point - it's better to call setter function once

```js
const [number, setNumber] = useState(3);
const [timePickerList, setTimePickerList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  setTimePickerList((prev) => {
    const list = [...prev];
    for(let i = 0; i < number ; i += 1) { 
      list.concat([]);
    }

    return list;
  })
}, [number])
```

Comment: thanks man for take your time and your awnser it's also one of the way